# How to filter blank product image from catalogsearch and catalog in magento by observer

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

i need to filter blank image product in magento from catalog and catalogsearch.
but it working fine on catalog. bt not fine in catalog search.

I got error when search product in search....

```
  Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'e.small_image' in 'where clause'"
```

### my observer config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Nine_Catalog>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Nine_Catalog>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <events>
            <catalog_block_product_list_collection>
                <observers>
                    <filter_blank_image> // unique idrntifer
                     <type>model</type>
                        <class>Nine_Catalog_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>filterBlankImage</method>
                    </filter_blank_image>
                </observers>
            </catalog_block_product_list_collection>
        </events>
        </global>
</config>


my observer
------------------
 class Nine_Catalog_Model_Observer extends Varien_Event_Observer{

    public function filterBlankImage(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {

        $collection = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();

       return  $collection->addAttributeToFilter('small_image',array('neq'=>'no_selection'));

    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the attribute as "Use in product listing" to Yes in order to use it in a flat collection.